# Installing Dual Boot Ubuntu 64 bit 13.10 along side Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Tags: dual-boot

I am planning on installing the 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10 along side Win 8.1 Enterprise .My PC is home built from around 2005. I already partitioned the C: drive such that the physical drive C now has the C drive for Win 8.1 and that same physical drive also has a logical drive called F. I allocated about 15 gigs for this logical F drive. The D drive is the DVD that has the Ubuntu Live DVD/Ready to install Ubuntu on it. So my question is should I wipe out the F drive by reallocating this 15 gig space back to the C drive, and then install Ubuntu and let Ubuntu do the partitioning, or is it better the way I have it right now? I am looking for the easiest Ubuntu install with minimal hassle.

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: did you had only three partitions?

Comment: I did as you said, but I never got the choice for, "Install Ubuntu along side Windows". I only got wipe out windows or something else basically. So if I choose something else then I get another screen which for some reason I can't include in this post. I am wondering if there is a way to force the live DVD to offer me the choice to install along side Windows?

Comment: Here is the screen shot [ss] (http://james2013.batcave.net/ss.htm)

Comment: jim,i updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Exit the ubuntu installer and install gparted partition editor by running the below commands on the terminal,

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted
  ```
- Then resize the windows partition and then create an ext4 partition for installing Ubuntu.
- After that,run the ubuntu installer,and choose *something else* option.Then install ubuntu on the created ext4 partition.If it asks to create a swap partition,then create a swap partition of size equal to double the size of RAM(applicable for only low sized RAM's).

Comment: Thanks Avinash for the info. I have a physical hard drive 0 called the C drive and then I decided to partition it to get it ready for Ubuntu. But will do as you have said and reallocate that space back to the C drive thru Windows tools and then try the, "Install along side Windows"

Comment: I absolutely will check off your work. I can't get back to this for a while, but will let you know either way. But I have saved your instruction set and hoping for the best.

Comment: try my answer,and getback to me if any error occurs.

Comment: Update 1: Avinash I got to terminal then tried sudo apt-get update and I got an error. So I tried sudo and sudo is being found because I got a list of options on how to use sudo. But here is something I found out. I went back into computer management for Windows and I shrunk the primary partition so now I have C: and unallocated space. And this is the key here, do not try to format this space or assign it a drive letter via the Windows, 'make simple volume'. So now when I boot the Ubuntu DVD, what happens is now I am prompted for, 'Install Ubuntu along side of Windows'.

Comment: Update 2: When I first shrunk my C partition down to say 68 GB, I was only left with say 9GB in the unallocated space. And now when I am in Ubuntu it takes that 9 GB and reports back, 'you have only 2GB to install Ubuntu do you wish to proceed?' So I started messing with the partition table and noticed Windows takes up the 68 GB and then 7 GB is somehow sitting there maybe for swap space - Ubuntu did this. I was trying to rearrange mount points or boot points or wipe out the 7 GB and make the entire 9 GB where I want to install, but I was not sure what I was doing so I canceled the operation.

Comment: So I have another question, If I add another hard drive to this PC and then using BIOS all the time choose the boot sequence can I have Windows on one hard drive and Ubuntu on the other? In other words Windows does not know of Ubuntu and visa versa?

Comment: Boot ubuntu live disk then install gparted and upload its screenshot.from that tell me how much space did you want to allocate for windows and ubuntu?

Comment: Avinash the problem is I cannot increase the size of the partition size for Ubuntu because Windows basically says it needs 68GB for a disk size due to unmovable files. I tried to defrag, optimize and as it turns out the MOST I can allocate to Ubuntu would be 9GB. I am not going to count on gparted, qparted or anything else to restructure my hard drive with. I think I am going to get another HD from another PC and try and work it with 2 hard drives with Windows on one and Ubuntu on the other.

Comment: jimf, i will help to increase your ubuntu partition size.If you had enough space for increasing its size,then why do go for another hard-disk?